# R: lm and biglm producing different answers

Tags: r

Why are "lm" and "biglm" producing different estimates? Consider the code below:

```
a = as.data.frame(cbind(y=rnorm(1000000), x1=rnorm(1000000), x2=rnorm(1000000)))
m1 = lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=a); summary(m1)

library(biglm)
m2 = biglm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=a); summary(m2)
```

It makes no difference if biglm processes in chunks or not - the final estimates are different from that produced by lm.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this using the code provided (I'm seeing no appreciable difference between `lm` and `biglm` esimates). Could you paste the printouts from the two `summary` calls please.

Comment: I can't see how you expect to get useful answers without providing more information about your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as answer simply due to length:

```
m2$qr

$D
[1] 1.000000e+06 1.001150e+06 9.993772e+05

$rbar
[1] -8.581350e-04 -8.116662e-04 -1.225233e-03  

$thetab
[1]  7.863159e-04 -4.276900e-04 -1.552812e-03   # these are the coefficients

Rgames: m1$coefficients
  (Intercept)            x1            x2 
 7.846869e-04 -4.295926e-04 -1.552812e-03
```

So, yes, the coefficients are slightly different.  For example, the intercepts differ by 0.2% .  Whether this sort of difference has any effect on the quality of your fitted line depends rather a  lot on what you intend to do with your fit.  Integration?  guaranteed no problem.  Extrapolation?  always risky, but not because the slopes differ by 0.5% .
I would strongly recommend that at the very least you run some test cases which fit, say
`f(x) =  g(x) +runif(N) ; h(x)= g(x) +runif(N)  #runif will return different sets of RVs`

,and see if lm and biglm return significantly different coefficients from the original g(x) values.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Carl. In this made-up example, the difference is not large. But in my actual dataset (which is too large to post), the difference is several orders of magnitude.

Comment: What happens if you take a small representative sample of your dataset?  Alternatively,  if the difference is that large, you should plot your (full) data and the two fitted curves, and see what looks reasonable.

Comment: OK, the dataset may be too large to post, but you can at least post the results to show us there's a big difference.  What are the results of `cov2cor(vcov(model))` , i.e. are the estimates strongly correlated?  Are the differences in estimates large relative to the standard errors?