# Predict with biglm get incorrect result comparing to lm

Tags: r, lm

I fit a model with `biglm` and `lm`, the returned model summary are the same (with the difference of just formatting). However when I use them to predict the same dataset, they produce different results. `lm` model is correct comparing to if I manually calculate them by hand using model coefficients. But biglm model is incorrect.

Here are the models:

```
m1 <- biglm(cost ~ d + v + zi, data = tl)

m2 <- lm(cost ~ d + v + zi, data = tl)
```

Here is a small piece of the model summaries:

```
m1: 

d:  coef 473.9196

m2: 

d: coef 4.739e+02
```

the rest of the model coefficients are matching and the same as illustrated above. However, when I use the model to predict, the results are different: m1 != m1

```
t1$m1 <- predict(m1, t1)

t1$m2 <- predict(m2, t1)
```

i tried to use predict.biglm() but got an error saying the function doesn't exist.

I also looked at this post ([R: lm and biglm producing different answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711915/r-lm-and-biglm-producing-different-answers)) and am sure it is not the reason.

The dataset is too big so I don't know how to share it here. And it also might take a while for me to de-code some of the information first.

But here is a small piece comparing of results which shows the predict is quite different.

```
      m1         m2
1798.831,  2365.868
1801.074,  2368.112
1482.508,  2351.042
```

Comment: can your share your data so the community can run your code?

Comment: how different are the predictions?

Comment: let me try to figure out how to add data and example.

Comment: okay, so they're very different.  are there different defaults to how missing data is handled?? (idk) Try not assigning the predictions back to your dataframe, and have a look at them. `p1 <- predict(m1, t1);
p2 <- predict(m2, t1);   length(as.numeric(p1)); length(p2) ; plot(as.numeric(p1), p2)` . I would also check by running your code again in a fresh R session making sure the original models are the same

Comment: @user20650, I did what you recommended: 
x1 <- predict(m1, t1)
x2 <- predict(m2, t1)
length(as.numeric(x1)) = 26098
length(as.numeric(x2)) = 26098
which is the same as the t1 length. 

the graph of plot(as.numeric(x1), x2) is a positive correlated trend plot.  

I almost think maybe biglm object is formatted differently so that the prediction is off by 1 row or something. Because the code runs correctly and the model summary is the same.

Comment: Well at least the predictions are the same length - i dont think they should be off by one row though. You could try adding some data (just enough observations to reproduce the error) to http://pastebin.com/ if you are able to share it.

Comment: @user20650, 
thanks for your comments so far. 
I will figure out how to do that. 
But so far they way I wrote the biglm syntax is correct, right? And I don't need to write as predict.biglm(), correct?

Comment: syntax looks fine (no the relevant predict method will be applied) . Example code the same as yours has no problem .. `m1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, mtcars) ;
p1 <- predict(m1, mtcars) ;

m2 <- biglm(mpg ~ wt + disp , mtcars) ;
p2 <- predict(m2, mtcars) ;
all.equal(p1, as.numeric(p2), check.attributes = F, use.names = F)`

Answer (score 0):

After a long day, I finally figured out the issue. 
I know biglm method requires the training and testing datasets have records for all factor levels. So when I was processing the dataset, I added 1 record of each missing factor level into the dataset (similar to the adding dummies method posted by another thread cited above).

However(!!), I didn't update the factor levels using factor() function. In this case, the biglm model runs fine and syntax is ok. But the model prediction results is not!!

Anyway, after I update the factor levels, it worked just fine.